# Can I update my android system although the USB port is broken?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, usb

The USB port of my LG-p500 is not capable of exchanging data anymore (the device or any `dmesg` do not show up when connected to a computer). Charging still works, fortunately.

Due to some annoying software bugs (Android 2.2, original LG supplied), I'd like to update the operating system to a newer Android version.

Do I have any chance to upgrade?

---- EDIT ----

For completeness, I include a screen of the update notification screen (Menu -> Update notification). It says it is updated, but the version V10R_00 was the one supplied initially with the phone. Furthermore, it tells me to connect it to the *PC suite*, a LG software.

[image: screen of update notification]

Comment: The non-idiomatic English in that notification makes it sound like a virus -- "set in version"?

Comment: @offby1 Or it could be a developer with bad English. There are more of those. (BTW I think you meant malware, not virus since currently the latter is not a threat on android)

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of options. The easiest would be just to turn on your wifi and download the latest carrier-supplied update to your SD Card and update your phone that way (assuming that for some reason the OTA update isn't working).

Comment: Logos, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how I would do what you suggest. Could you maybe link to a guide or be more specific? For completeness, I have now included the update notification screen in the question.

Comment: Sebastian: I can't link to a guide or be more specific without knowing what carrier your bought your phone from.  Each carrier has it's own method, which can vary from phone to phone. It would probably be easiest just to call your carrier's tech support and ask them, really - they can walk you thru updating manually.